# How can I deploy CLR assembly to a remote server?

Tags: .net, deployment, clr, assemblies

Does .NET provide the framework to upload a CLR assembly to a remote server?

I'm implementing a custom remote "testing" server for some bespoke functionality and want to allow the user to upload unit tests, in the form of a CLR assembly, and some test files to the remote server. (These are bespoke tests; not C# unit tests.)

So does .NET provide this as a built-in feature or do I need to implement my own transfer mechanism (e.g. SFTP or such like)?

Could I use WCF to transfer the raw DLL file?

(Or is there a better way to design this?)

Thanks

[EDIT]

Additional background info: I already have something in place locally the loads an assembly at runtime from the local file system. I want to move the server to a remote machine and use WCF to trigger running tests, but also upload the assembly to the remote server at the same time.

Comment: .NET needs to be installed, you cannot just upload files.

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks. Sorry it wasn't clear, but I sort of assumed that; my test server application is a .NET app - I want to upload "plug-in" assemblies.

Comment: Do you actually want to upload a CLR?  Or just an assembly you have built? The CLR is part of the .NET Framework and needs to be installed. For assemblies you build, it depends, you can publish depending on what you want to deploy?

Comment: @ChristianFredh - sorry, a typo on my part (edited now) - I want to upload an assembly that has been built. (As an example, I see that you can write CLR SQL Server functions and deploy them to the server - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dahcx0ww(v=vs.90).aspx - I want to deploy my own assemblies to my own custom server (not SQL Server))